# How to expand on one of my own questions after several days

Tags: discussion

I asked a question over two weeks ago: [Locating evenly spaced spikes in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892969/locating-evenly-spaced-spikes-in-time-series)

People provided good pointer in the comments, but nobody posted a proper answer.  At the moment, we had lost some datasets that where giving us trouble, so even if I knew we could not use the provided hints, there was no way for me to show it.

Now I've found a dataset that shows my problem in detail, but I'm not sure what to do.

Do I edit my old question and add the new data? Close it and create a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could edit it to add the new data since there are useful comments at the question but it won't be shown at the *Unanswered newest* where I think most users look.

Another solution is to close that one and create a new one containing the dataset and what was useful from the comments. But every deleted questions count towards question bans, which may be a problem in future

And there's always the *bounty* possibility if the others don't work :)

Comment: Deleted questions count towards question bans, which may be a problem for the OP in future.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, doesn't that thing occur after several deleted questions/low rated question and if you are unproductive on the site?

Comment: @Yes, exact formula of how the ban is calculated is unpublished. But _every deletion counts_. OP should edit current question. In this case, as there are no answers, there is no risk of invalidating current answers by editing the question. So editing is the best option.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, I slightly modified the answer after discussing with you. Still there is little risk for an active user to get question ban. You receive a warning first (I did).

Comment: I get a warning like this: *Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?

Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.* because my questions are very specific and only help me. Active as in answering/flagging/editing questions, I think that's why they still letting me ask questions :)